# Logarithm equation $X'=Ce^{-X}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider following ODE:
$$X'(t)=Ce^{-X(t)}$$
where $X(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,$C$ is $n\times n$ constant matrix.
I construct this equation by the property of **Matrix logarithm**.

But how to solve this ODE if I don't know logarithm?

Further more, change the $C$ constant to :

1. $A(t)$, which is a matrix respect to $t$.
2. $P(t)$, which is a matrix respect to $t$ but with period $T$.

How to find the solution? **Existence**? Uniqueness? (Given initial value condition $X(t_0)_{i,j}=1$ for any $i,j \in [1..n]$, namely $X(t_0)$ is the all-$1$-matrix.)

Comment: 1) It may now happen that $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ do not commute for $t≠s$. Then the situation becomes tricky. But there are simple cases that can be handled. 2) Here you should have a look at Floquet theory.

Comment: Without logarithms. Assume that X(t)X(t) and X(s)X(s)  commute for t≠s. Then $d/dt e{^X(t)}=C$ and $e{^X(t)}=Ct+D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C,D\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $D$ has no eigenvalues in $(-\infty,0]$. We consider the ODE $X'=Ce^{-X},X(0)=\log(D)$; locally, it has a unique solution.

If $CD=DC$, then this solution is $X(t)=\log(tC+D)$ where $\log(.)$ is the principal logarithm. Thus $X(t)$ is a polynomial in $tC+D$. Consequently, $X(s)X(t)=X(t)X(s)$ and the result of Urgje: $e^X=tC+D$ is correct in this case.

If $CD\not= DC$, then the unique solution is no more the one above. We obtain a generalization of the $\log(.)$ function.